# terminate matlab running through nohup and access the workspace variables

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, background-process, nohup

I am using nohup to run a matlab script in background on a linux server. Last part of the script has commands to save the workspace variables to the disk. In my case, I do not want to wait for completion of the script.  Is is possible to terminate the running script midway and access/save the variables existing at that particular stage to the disk.

Comment: if you're running with `nohup myprog &`, you can just close the terminal and it will continue running ignoring SIGHUP signal.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `nohup`, you do not have a nice way to communicate with your program after the terminal is closed. What can help is the window manager `screen` (take a look at `man screen`). Even after the session is detached from the terminal once you are still able to get control over your program back.